# How do you loop through already existing values in an arrray after populating it?

Tags: python, arrays, pseudocode

I need to loop through an array and be able to create a populate an array using pseudocode or python.

I have tried to create and populate an array, but cannot loop through the values.

Comment: In pseudocode you can do this in whatever way you want.

Comment: When you say array do you mean a python list, or a numpy array?  Could you show the code of what you have tried and what is your desired output?

Comment: I mean a python list.  I have tried creating a simple array. ARRAY names[5] 
names[0] = "Ahmad" 
names[1] = "Ben" 
names[2] = "Catherine" 
names[3] = "Dana" 
names[4] = "Elijah" 
PRINT(names[3])
 Now i want to loop through these values instead of printing one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp :

You can create a `list` like this:

```
cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
```

Then you can add another `item` to this `list` like this:

```
cars.append("Toyota")
```

Finally, if you want to loop (`iterate`) through the `list`, you do like this:

```
another_cars = ["Ford", "Volvo", "BMW"]
for x in another_cars:
  print(x)
```

Also, if you want to print the whole array, just print it :)

```
print(cars)
```